# Make terse Python lambda code in PySpark more understandable

Tags: python, lambda

I've been able to get pyspark running a linear regression example using Anaconda on a test cluster. It's pretty cool.

My next step is to make the code a little more templatized for our analysts. Specifically I'd like to rewrite the following lambda function as a regular function so it's more accessible to our current skill levels in Python. I've made a number of attempts, but the combination of map, lambda, and numpy.array all at once is confusing.

```
data = sc.textFile("hdfs://nameservice1:8020/spark_input/linear_regression/lpsa.data")
parsedData = data.map(lambda line: array([float(x) for x in line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')]))
```

Entire program is below. Any help appreciated.

```
#!/opt/tools/anaconda/bin python

from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.regression import LinearRegressionWithSGD
from numpy import array

conf = SparkConf()
conf.setMaster("local")
conf.setAppName("Python - Linear Regression Test")
conf.set("spark.executor.memory", "1g")

sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

# Load and parse the data

data = sc.textFile("hdfs://nameservice1:8020/spark_input/linear_regression/lpsa.data")
parsedData = data.map(lambda line: array([float(x) for x in line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')]))

# Build the model
numIterations = 50
model = LinearRegressionWithSGD.train(parsedData, numIterations)

# Evaluate model on training examples and compute training error
valuesAndPreds = parsedData.map(lambda point: (point.item(0), model.predict(point.take(range(1, point.size)))))

MSE = valuesAndPreds.map(lambda (v, p): (v-p)**2).reduce(lambda x, y: x + y) / valuesAndPreds.count()
print("training Mean Squared Error = " + str(MSE))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def line_to_array(line):
    space_separated_line = line.replace(',', ' ')
    string_array = space_separated_line.split(' ')
    float_array = map(float, string_array)
    return array(float_array)

parsedData = map(line_to_float_array, data)
```

Or, equivalently,

```
def line_to_array(line):
    space_separated_line = line.replace(',', ' ')
    string_array = space_separated_line.split(' ')
    float_array = [float(x) for x in string_array]
    return array(float_array)

parsedData = [line_to_float_array(line) for line in data]
```

Comment: AH, now I see. Thanks Amadan!!

Answer (score 0):

Amadan's answer is correct within the confines of Python itself, which was the original question. However, the implementation looks slightly different when working with RDDs (Resilient Distributed Datasets) in Spark, as Spark's map function is used rather than Python's:

```
# Declare functions at startup:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def line_to_float_array(line):
        string_array = line.replace(',', ' ').split(' ')
        float_array = map(float, string_array)
        return array(float_array)

#
#
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)

# Load and parse the data
data = sc.textFile("hdfs://nameservice1:8020/sparkjeb/lpsa.data")
parsedData = data.map(line_to_float_array)
```